# Explicit example of Gershgorin circle theorem edge case

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The Gershgorin Circle Theorem states that if the union of $m$ of the discs is connected, and disjoint from any discs not in the union, then it contains $m$ eigenvalues of the matrix.

I am looking for a way to construct a matrix for which one of the Gershgorin discs contains no eigenvalues.

Comment: Do you look for counter examples or...? Antidiagonal matrices are good candidates.

Comment: @algebraicpavel I'm seeking a counterexample to the statement: "Every gershgorin disc of a matrix contains an eigenvalue of that matrix". I think an antidiagonal matrix will do the trick, thank you.

Comment: Doesn't the wikipedia entry contain two examples?

Comment: I looked at the page and don't see what you're referring to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way is to construct a matrix with zeroes along the diagonal so that all of the Gershgorin discs are centered at the origin.  Then set the other entries so that one row has just one relatively small nonzero entry so that the Gershgorin disc associated with that row is small, therefore giving a good chance that it will not contain an eigenvalue.

For example,
$$ \left( \begin{matrix}
 0 & 1\\
 4 & 0 \end{matrix} \right)$$
has Gershgorin discs of radii $1$ and $4$ and eigenvalues $2$ and $-2$.  Neither eigenvalue lies within the smaller disc.  The reason why the first disc, $D_1$, does not contain an eigenvalue is that $D_1$ corresponds to eigenvectors whose first entry is the largest in absolute value (to understand why, study the [proof of the theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem#Statement_and_proof)).  In this example, there are no such eigenvectors.